# Xamarin Forms Android project won't deploy if I have application tag in Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-activity, xamarin.android, admob

I have a Xamarin Forms project and is trying to add Admob using this [article](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/388225/xamarinforms-39unable-to-get-provider-comgoogleand.html).

One of them involve declaring the `AdActivity` in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.name" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="Example.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:label="@string/appName" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However after I add the `<application>` tag, I couldn't deploy anymore (the Build is still successful). At first an error shows up asking me to disable "Use Fast Deployment" but after I disabled it, nothing shows up anymore.

I have tried to only have an empty `<application></application>` tag, the problem is still there. Removing it would help the app deployed and run but I encounter an exception that `AdActivity` is not declared obviously. I suspected it could be duplicate declaration so in my `MainActivity` file I removed every declarative attribute and only write `[Activity]` but the problem is still there.

What is the problem? I think I can solve it either by:

- Somehow declare an `[Activity]` attribute on `AdActivity`. Unfortunately it's sealed.
- Add `<application>` tag. Seem like everyone was able to do that without this problem.

Comment: you have **two** `application` tags

Comment: @Jason darn... I spent hours and gave up. can't believe this... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jason btw a lot of people have good stuff to say about you! https://twitter.com/Saamerm/status/1431376159242129412